# Unable To Extract Data From Webpage Using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am have added the lines of code as suggested. I still get the same error message.[image: Error - Only Assignment Call, Increment.... Can Be Used As A Statement]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do something with the text. For example, assign to some variable:

```
string pressureToday = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(xpathExpression)).Text;
```

Comment: I have added the code as suggested. But, I get the same error message.

Comment: I commented out lines 39 & 46 out & it worked.. Many Thanks.

Comment: I have another error. My research (from google & stackoverflow) suggests that it is a formatting issue. Here it is, please:  

https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/27406/error-an-unhandled-exception-of-type-system-formatexception-occurred-in-msco