# Error - An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: selenium-webdriver

[image: Error - The Name 'CultureInfo' Does Not Exist In The Current Context][image: Error - An Unhandled Exception Of type 'System.FormatException' Occurredl In Mscorlib.dll]

I get this error message when I run this code:

This is my code:

```
        //Wait for web element to become visible
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(15000);

        //Click on Table button
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("detail-table-view")).Click();

        //Obtaining pressure For 2100 hours today
        //driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='hourly']/div[3]/table/tfoot/tr[3]/td[6]")).Text;
        string pressureToday = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='hourly']/div[3]/table/tfoot/tr[3]/td[16]")).Text;


        //Click On next day button on website, i.e. Wednesday 24/05/2017
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='blq-content']/div[7]/div[2]/ul/li[3]/a/div/h3/span")).Click();

        //Obtain pressure for 2100 Hours tomorrow
        //driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='hourly']/div[3]/table/tfoot/tr[3]/td[16]")).Text;
        string pressureTomorrow = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='hourly']/div[3]/table/tfoot/tr[3]/td[15]")).Text;


        //Subtract the two values above and then 'echo' the result in Selenium
        int val1 = Int32.Parse(driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='hourly']/div[3]/table/tfoot/tr[3]/td[15]")).Text);
        int val2 = Int32.Parse(driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='hourly']/div[3]/table/tfoot/tr[3]/td[16]")).Text);

        int difference = val1 - val2;
      System.Console.WriteLine("Difference is: " + difference);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the text you get contains , or . and you cant convert that to whole number directly. And if you already got the text, there is no need to find it again.

Try it like this:

```
var _pressureToday = Double.Parse(pressureToday,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
var _pressureTomorrow = Double.Parse(pressureTomorrow,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

var difference = _pressureToday - _pressureTomorrow;
```

Comment: I put that code in & I get an error message: "The name 'CultureInfo' does not exist in the current context."

My research led me to this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9760237/what-does-cultureinfo-invariantculture-mean

I have also added a screen shot of the error message. Thanks.

Comment: You can mouseover the problem, and Visual Studio will auto suggest how to solve it, just need to use System.Globalization;